# Inputting list elements into function

Tags: python, list, function, spotfire

I was wondering if there is a way to take the elements in a list and insert them into the inputs of a function. So for example

```py
def function(x,y,z):
    #does stuff

def main():
   changing_list=[8,9,10]
   function(changing_list)
```

I am using the function `GetRows` in `Spotfire`, which allows different amounts of input to be used. So I am planning to put the names of rows I am going to use into the list and then use it to give the inputs into the function. If there is a better way of doing this please tell me, I can't put in the inputs before hand due to me not knowing which rows I will be using beforehand. If there is something unclear please ask me to clarify. An important point that I noticed that I may have left out after looking at the answers. I cannot adjust the code in the function due to me not have access to it. Also the function might not always accept 3 inputs, it will vary depending on the what happens when the code runs before hand, the list may have 5 elements in one run and 1 element in the next one.

Comment: may be like this `function(l[o],l[1],l[2])` or `a,b,c=changing_list, function(a,b,c)`

Comment: @Deadpool Did you forget about unpacking, in my answer?

Comment: yes i missed that, var arg right `*changing_list` and `changing_list` will be tuple of inputs @U10-Forward

Comment: @Deadpool Correct.

Comment: @Deadpool I cant use the first way, since it may not always be 3 inputs. It may be 5 or 1. The function that is being used can adapt for it.

Comment: Then use var args as answered by U10 @NikitaBelooussov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line of:

```
   function(changing_list)
```

To:

```
   function(*changing_list)
```

If you're in Python 3.

Use:

```
   function(l[0], l[1], l[2])
```

Comment: why cant I use *change_list in python 3. Did they remove this function?

Comment: @NikitaBelooussov No you can only use that in python 3

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the single star * which unpacks the sequence. This allows you to do this:

```
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y

nums = (1, 5)
s = mul(*nums)
```

This will unpack the tuple. It actually executes as:

```
s = mul(1, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have requested 3 variables for your function when defining it, but you only give it one list. Try this:

```
def function(xs):
    xs[0] = 1
    xs[1] = 2
    xs[2] = 3

def main():
    changing_list = [8, 9, 10]
    function(changing_list)
```

Now your function will take your list, and change it to `[1, 2, 3]`. You can use `print` to check.